# Is there an app that will let me edit track information (title/artist)?

Tags: software-recommendation, ios, music

I wonder if is there any app for the iOS 5 that will let me edit the artist or title of my music?

The music is currently synced through iTunes and stored in the music app, but please let me know if there are any alternatives. I am open to jail breaking the device if there are no other alternatives.

Comment: I know VLC on Mac can do it, and now wonder if the iPhone app can too?

Comment: From the description: "VLC Streamer streams movies from your computer (Mac or PC) over your wifi to your iDevice." They don't mention audio at all so it's safe to assume that VLC can't edit tags on iOS.

Comment: It is also worth noting that VLC is only available on Jailbroken devices, or by compiling it from source. The latter requires being a registered iOS developer or cajoling someone who is to provision your device and get you a binary that the developer has compiled & signed.

Comment: If your music is synced through iTunes, why is it a requirement to edit the metadata on your iOS device? In particular, why do you need to do this on iOS when there are *so* many available Mac OS X and Windows solutions for editing music metadata.

Comment: I guess I got it before they pulled it, but I can add files to it through iTunes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To date, it is still not possible to edit song metadata on an iOS device, nor it be recommended if it was possible. Songs you get from sources directly onto the device (Spotify, GrooveShark, iTunes Store) all contain correct information. If you have damaged metadata inside media you've acquired elsewhere, look into software that will clean it up before syncing it over.

Comment: Content from GrooveShark is much less guaranteed to contained "correct information" than iTunes/Spotify.

Comment: @JasonSalaz None are guaranteed to 'contain' the correct information all the time. That doesn't change the point of the post.

Comment: I have music for which iTunes is not correct thus it is needed to edit song metadata

Answer (score 4):

Given the rather strict sandboxing applied in iOS this is most probably impossible to achieve without jailbraking the device.

Comment: What about with jailbreaking it?

Answer (score 1):

Thumbgenius just released an app called [TuneUp](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tuneup/id463150721?mt=8) that does exactly this and more.

Comment: Well, this does not happen on your iOS device directly. Quote «Simply download our iPhone and MAC app, **log into facebook on both ends** and you instantly have access to your iTunes library at home.» ... «NOTE: this app requires that you know how to set up port forwarding on your router at home.»

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on @patrix's answer, this Yahoo Answers [post](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090828161943AA92UcO) indicates that there isn't currently any app that will do it, even on a jailbroken device. This [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060623/how-do-i-modify-song-info-e-g-id3-tags-aac-info-on-songs-that-are-in-the-med) also indicates that there are no APIs to do this at the moment.

However, there are music editors like [Houkusai](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090828161943AA92UcO) ([iTunes link](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hokusai-audio-editor/id432079746)). In its app description, it claims to:

> - Import tracks from your iPod music library

However, it's likely to be overkill for what you're looking for, since it's meant to be a music editor and not as a track editor.

In summary, in a search for track/id3 editors, I've found only applications that will work on a computer, not on an iDevice.

Comment: Houkusai isn't relevant to what the questioner is looking for, but the Stack Overflow post is - it wouldn't be possible to use the app that the questioner wants on a non-jailbroken device. I guess it would be possible to have an app that remembered the edits you wanted to make and synced them with a desktop app that changed the track information in the parent iTunes library...

Answer (score 0):

If you want do it with iOS program, you have to jailbreak it.
Also you can try iTunes, MediaMonkey or other same software

Answer (score -2):

YouTubetoMp3 - allows you to name artist, album, etc. metadata and then import to library, even if one already exists.

Comment: Could you add a link to the software you recommended? Or are you asking a question yourself?